# How do I manage grounding when installing a metal extension on a plastic box?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I've been repairing an outlet that's not supposed to be recessed, but is, so I purchased a [box extension](https://www.rona.ca/en/box-extension) from the local hardware store. When I tried to put it in, I realized it interferes with the grounding wire going to the grounding strip in the plastic box I was trying to install it in. I don't think there's any way to run a wire to that screw terminal with this metal ring installed.

The shape of the box extension is a continuous metal ring the shape of a box, with flanges on top and bottom. There are no holes on the sides. I intend to use shims to bring the receptacle level with the drywall with the longer screws included.

What is the code-compliant way of grounding this extension (and the box, if required)?

If it's of assistance, here's a photo of the interference:

[image: photo of the situation]

Comment: Can you try taking that extender back and getting a plastic extender instead, or will that not do the trick?

Comment: Hardware stores here are quite bad. This particular one didn't offer any other types. But a plastic one is probably the correct solution.

Comment: You should be able to order plastic box extensions in online without an issue (I know offhand that Arlington makes one, but it's only really suitable for fixing depth issues, not volume issues)

Comment: I appear to have resolved this by routing the wire back from the screw on the grounding bar along the same path it comes in (beside the box extension) then flipping the receptacle upside down so the ground screw is on the top right. To clarify: it goes back around the outside of the extension, then around the lip before coming back out the middle. I will write up a full answer once I get it completely installed (forgot to get shims).